# observing linearity in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We use superposition principle to account for linearity in a equation if we have a equation
$$f(x)=y=2x$$
Then we can say that for $x_1$: $y_1=f(x_1)=2x_1$

and for $x_2$: $y_2=f(x_2)=2x_2.$

This equation will be linear if $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2).$

This is the case to be observed for simple algebraic equations.

But what would be equation if we have been observing *Differential equations*?

If I consider a simple case of first order differential equation 
$$\dot y+x^2=4=f(x,y)\tag{1}$$

For $y_1$ to be a solution to the equation $(1)$ we have:
$$x_1,y_1:\;\dot y_1+x_1^2=4=f(x_1,y_1)\tag{2}$$

For $y_2$ to be a homogeneous solution to the equation $(1)$ we have:
$$x_2,y_2:\;\dot y_2+x_2^2=0=f(x_2,y_2)\tag{3}$$

For $x=x_1+x_2;y= y_1+y_2$ to the equation $(1)$ we have
$$\dot{(y_1+y_2)}+x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_1x_2=4=f(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\neq f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)$$

Clearly here $f(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\neq f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)$ and we end up with an additional $2x_1x_2.$ So the principle of linearity shouldn't hold here but we know that this is an example of first order linear differential equation!

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linearity of differential equations ara characterized by the linearity of the corresponding differential operators. If $L(D)y= f(x)$ is a diferential equation with differential operator $L(D)$ (where $D$ stands for $\frac{d}{dx}$), then if $L(D)$ is linear operator, namely if it satisfes the condition $L(D)(c_1y_1+c_2y_2)= c_1L(D)y_1+c_2L(D)y_2$ for all solutions of DE and for all scalars $c_1$ and $c_2$, then the equation is linear, otherwise it is nonlinear. In your case, you have $L(D)= y'= Dy$(which is linear) and $f(x)=4-x^2$.